# Flask - How can I retrieve the value of input by the type?

Tags: python, forms, flask

How can I retrieve the value passed by POST request by type of input?

When I search, I only find the ones that retrieve the input `name` attribute (for example: `request.form['text']`, when the entry name is *"text"*). **I'd like to redeem by type, not by name**.

*Note*:
There are multiple input tags, not just one. In that way, if I'm not mistaken, there should be something like the `getlist` method.

I tried using `request.get_data(as_text=True)`, but the type of output is unicode and I would like array.

```
@app.route('/finalizar', methods=['POST'])
def preencherExames():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text = request.get_data(as_text=True)
        return render_template('finalizar.html', title='Selecionar exames', results=text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getlist` if you want a list of values:

```
request.form.getlist('name')
```

Comment: request.form.getlist('name') is just returning by the name, right? But the problem is that i have multiples input (type text) with different names. So i prefer to retrieve by the type (text).

Comment: i think you cant do it with python  but jquery yes using like this $('input[type=radio]');

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading Flask internals correctly you don't have access to the type property of your form field when it gets to Flask

if you can modify names of the fields in your form I would suggest something like this:

```
for form_field_name in request.form.keys():
    if form_field_name.endswith('_text'):
        for value in request.form.getlist(form_field_name):
            # process values
```

where you add suffix _text to your fields of the type text

I know it is ugly, but I hope it will help